# xidel: how to retrieve value from JSON key containing dots(.)?

Tags: json, shell, xidel

I try to retrieve `1` in :

```
$ cat object.json 
{
    "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
    "kind": "Deployment",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ xidel -e '($json).metadata.annotations["deployment.kubernetes.io/revision"]' -s object.json 
{
  "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1"
}
```

Tried

```
'($json).metadata.annotations."deployment.kubernetes.io/revision"'
'($json).metadata.annotations.("deployment.kubernetes.io/revision")'
'($json).metadata.annotations.(deployment.kubernetes.io/revision)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hardly ever use the dot-notation, because as far as I know in terms of capabilities it's rather limited.

JSONiq notation:

```bash
-e '$json("metadata")("annotations")("deployment.kubernetes.io/revision")'
```

Xpath-like notation with the XPath 3.1 [`map:get()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-map-get) function:

```bash
-e '$json/metadata/annotations/map:get(.,"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision")'
```

XPath 3.1 ["?" lookup operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-lookup):

```bash
-e '$json?metadata?annotations?"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision"'
```

A combination of all notations:

```bash
-e '$json("metadata")/annotations?"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found:

```
$ xidel -e '($json).metadata.annotations(["deployment.kubernetes.io/revision"])' -s object.json
1
```

Is it a correct way to do it?